# MATLAB: Fast correlation computation for all indices in 2 vectors

Tags: matlab, pearson-correlation

I have 2 vectors A and B, each of length 10,000. For each of `ind=1:10000`, I want to compute the Pearson's correlation of `A(1:ind)` and `B(1:ind)`. When I do this in a for loop, it takes too much time. parfor does not work with more than 2 workers in my machine. Is there a way to do this operation fast and save results in a vector C (apparently of length 10,000 where the first element is NaN)? I found the question [Fast rolling correlation in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625574/fast-rolling-correlation-in-matlab), but this is a little different than what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method to compute cumulative correlation coefficient:

```
function result = cumcor(x,y)
    n = reshape(1:numel(x),size(x));
    sumx = cumsum(x);
    sumy = cumsum(y);
    sumx2 = cumsum(x.^2);
    sumy2 = cumsum(y.^2);
    sumxy = cumsum(x.*y);
    result = (n.*sumxy-sumx.*sumy)./(sqrt((sumx.^2-n.*sumx2).*(sumy.^2-n.*sumy2)));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

I suggest the following approach:

1. Pearson correlation can be calculated by using [the following formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Definition):
   [image]
2. calculating the accumulative mean of each of the random variabiles above efficiently is realtively easy
   (X, Y, XY, X^2, Y^2).
3. given the accumulative mean calculated in 2, we can calculate the accumulative std of X and Y.
4. given the accumulative std of X,Y and accumulative mean above, we can calculate the accumulative pearson coefficient.

**Code**

```
%defines inputs
N = 10000;
X = rand(N,1);
Y = rand(N,1);

%calculates accumolative mean for X, Y, X^2, Y^2, XY
EX = accumMean(X);
EY = accumMean(Y);
EX2 = accumMean(X.^2);
EY2 = accumMean(Y.^2);
EXY = accumMean(X.*Y);

%calculates accumolative pearson correlation
accumPearson = zeros(N,1);
for ii=2:N
    stdX = (EX2(ii)-EX(ii)^2).^0.5;
    stdY = (EY2(ii)-EY(ii)^2).^0.5;
    accumPearson(ii) = (EXY(ii)-EX(ii)*EY(ii))/(stdX*stdY);
end

%accumulative mean function, to be defined in an additional m file.
function [ accumMean ] = accumMean( vec )
accumMean = zeros(size(vec));
accumMean(1) = vec(1);
for ii=2:length(vec)
   accumMean(ii) = (accumMean(ii-1)*(ii-1) +vec(ii))/ii;
end

end
```

**Runtime**

for N=10000:

```
Elapsed time is 0.002096 seconds.
```

for N=1000000:

```
Elapsed time is 0.240669 seconds.
```

**Correctness**

Testing the correctness of the code above could be done by calculative the accumulative pearson coefficient by corr function, and comparing it to the result given from the code above:

```
%ground truth for correctness comparison
gt = zeros(N,1)
for z=1:N
    gt(z) = corr(X(1:z),Y(1:z));
end
```

Unfortunately, I dont have the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox, so I cant make this check.
I do think that it is a good start though, and you can continue from here :)